# addTextChangedListener is not working inside Base Adapter

Tags: android, sqlite

I have implemented a customized listview with name,price,quantity etc,

By default the quantity is 1 in all the list items.

If user changes one of the list item's quantity from 1 to 2 , then the changed quantity has to updated in the Sqlite database.

**Problem**

I tried using `addTextChangedListener` to get the updated data from user input and update it in the sqlite database as well. But `addTextChangedListener` is not working .

I am unable to update the required field in the database.

Below is the code where I use `addTextChangedListener`.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_cart, null);


        holder.tv_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name_cart);
        holder.tv_price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.price_cart);
        holder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_cart);
        holder.tv_model = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.model_cart);
        holder.tv_product = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.product_cart);
        holder.delete = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        holder.quantity = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        rowView.setTag(holder);



    }
    else

    holder = (Holder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.tv_name.setText(list_name.get(position));
    name = holder.tv_name.getText().toString();
    holder.tv_price.setText(list_price.get(position));
    price = holder.tv_price.getText().toString();
    holder.tv_model.setText(list_model.get(position));
    model = holder.tv_model.getText().toString();
    holder.tv_product.setText(list_productid.get(position));
    product = holder.tv_product.getText().toString();
    holder.quantity.setText(quant_items.get(position));
    quant = holder.quantity.getText().toString();





    holder.image.setImageBitmap(loadImageFromStorage(list_images.get(position)));
    image_new = holder.image.toString();


    holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            value = s.toString().trim();
            quant.replace(holder.quantity.getText().toString(), value);
            updateTable();

        }

    });


    final Holder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
            //SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getWritableDatabase();

            // db.onUpgrade(db1,0,1);


            deleteUser(finalHolder.tv_model.getText().toString());
            ListView list = (ListView)parent;
            cart_refresh.notifyDataSetChanged();
          list.setAdapter(cart_refresh);


            //  db.deleteContact(new Cart(holder.tv_name.getText().toString(),holder.tv_price.getText().toString()
            //     ,holder.image.toString(),holder.tv_model.getText().toString()));
        }
    });


    final View finalRowView = rowView;
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name_item = ((TextView) finalRowView.findViewById(R.id.name_cart)).getText().toString();
            String price_item = ((TextView) finalRowView.findViewById(R.id.price_cart)).getText().toString();
            model_item = ((TextView) finalRowView.findViewById(R.id.model_cart)).getText().toString();

            Intent in = new Intent(context, AddCart_FullImage.class);
            in.putExtra("model", model_item);
            in.putExtra("name", name_item);
            in.putExtra("price", price_item);
            context.startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}




private Bitmap loadImageFromStorage(String path) {

    try {
        File f = new File(path, "");
        f.canRead();
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        return b;


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
public void deleteUser(String userName)
{
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

    SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getWritableDatabase();
    try
    {
        db1.delete("cart", "model = ?", new String[]{userName});


        //cart_refresh.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        db.close();
    }



}
public void updateTable() {
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

    SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        db.updateContact(new Cart(name, price,image_new,model, product,value));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }



}
```

Any help would be really appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest issue is, that you're using fields instead of local variables.

```
quant = holder.quantity.getText().toString();
```

updates `quant` with every call to `getView()` so

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    value = s.toString().trim();
    quant.replace(holder.quantity.getText().toString(), value);
    updateTable();
}
```

will use the text field last bound to data and not the the one you added the listener to.

You need to take care of the scope of the variables you're using and introduce consistency to your model.

I would recommend a complete rewrite of the adapter without using any fields.